# Is submitting edits for a question multiple times until it is considered acceptable okay?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, etiquette, off-topic

I recently encountered a question I think could be useful to others if it were phrased better. The question had been flagged as off-topic originally, but I submitted an edit to nudge it into asking for the same solution but in an on-topic way. After the suggested edit I made was accepted I messaged a mod about removing the off-topic hold flag. They responded saying although it was now on topic, the question was still too broad.

Is it be considered okay to make another edit with the intent of narrowing the focus so that the asker might receive an answer to their question, or is editing multiple times not going to be received well? Alternatively, should I just ask another question addressing the same topic but phrased properly for the site and just link it in the comments of that question?

Here is a screenshot of the question and a [link to it](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/5524/what-non-recommended-video-cards-can-be-used-for-vr) as well as a screenshot of the edits I made.

[image: Screenshot of question at 8/18/2016 12:02 PM]

*This is the edited form of the question that is now too general.*

[image: Edits I made]

*Here are the edits I made.*

Comment: A link to the question you're talking about would be helpful to provide a concrete example. It would also provide some information which might be useful for an answer (e.g. are you *suggesting* edits, or do you have >2k rep on that site and can edit without review)?

Comment: Suggesting edits I'm not at a high rep there yet, I'll post a screenshot and a link so that the link isn't nonsensical in case the edit does get approved.

Answer (score 4):

I'll give you my opinion based on reviewing these kinds of edits, others may not agree...

If the edit is significant enough and improves the question to the point where it can be considered a good question<sup>*</sup> (or at least makes a good attempt at it) and brings it more in to scope—hopefully to the point where it can be reopened—then the edit should be more than welcome.

Closing a question isn't necessarily always dismissing the question out of hand—it's an invitation to improve the question to a standard that fits the StackExchange Q&A model. A lot of new users don't always understand that so helping them is never a bad thing.

If on the other hand you're simple fixing some spelling mistakes, slightly rephrasing the same thing but not making any significant changes—Don't bother. If there's no chance of the question being reopened then you're wasting reviewers time.

As for multiple edits, it depends on the quality of the edits. Remember someone has to review each one so submitting a bunch of piecemeal edits that don't significantly improve anything is going to annoy people. If you're making a good and significant effort to improve the question then that should be welcome.

<sup>*</sup> Good in an objective fits-the-intended-Q&A-model kind of way.

Comment: Thanks; what's your two cents on the one I'm looking at, if you don't mind.

Comment: It looks like an OK edit, but I don't know that site enough to know what is on or off-topic and how much of an improvement your edit makes in that regard or to give any specific advice sorry.

Comment: Thanks, it's understandable. It's a really specific site and in Beta no-less.

Comment: Best advice I can give is to ask the mods on that site